# A2LiX Translation Form - no errors printed

Tags: forms, symfony, a2lix-translation

I work with Symfony 2.4, KnpLabs DoctrineBehaviors bundle for translation in database, and A2LiX Translation Form for fields translation.

Form display and insertion in database work fine but errors for translation fields are not printed.

For example :

- the error of the field "photo" is print
- the error of the translatable field "title" is not print

Post.php

```
/**
* 
* @ORM\Column(name="photo", type="string", length=255)
* @Assert\NotBlank(message="no photo")
*/
private $photo;
```

PostTranslation.php

```
/**
* 
* @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
* @Assert\NotBlank(message="no title")
*/
private $title;
```

PostType.php

```
$builder
    ->add('translations', 'a2lix_translations')
    ->add('photo')
    ->add('submit', 'submit');
```

form.html.twig

```
<form method="post" novalidate {{form_enctype(form)}}>
    <p>{{ form_widget(form.translations) }}</p>
    <p>{{ form_label(form.photo, 'photo') }}<br />{{ form_widget(form.photo) }}</p>
    <p>{{ form_widget(form.submit) }}</p>
    <p>{{ form_widget(form._token) }}</p>
    <p>{{ form_errors(form.translations) }}</p>
    <p>{{ form_errors(form.photo) }}</p>
<form>
```

[When i submit the form, i have this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFTu0.jpg)
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

First update to the last version of A2lixTranslationFormBundle.
And check that you have well in your Post entity, the @Assert\Valid annotation on the $translations field.

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

 /**
  * @Assert\Valid
  */
 protected $translations;
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it inside YAML configuration, you can do this:

```
CRMPicco\GolfBundle\Entity\CourseGuide:
    properties:
        name:
            - NotBlank: ~
        translations:
            - Valid: ~
```